# string as xpath selector

Tags: xpath, xquery

I have a function that takes the result set as element and a string as args and I want to use this string as a selector inside the function.

```
function abc ($results as element()*, $element as xs:string)
 {
    for $g in distinct-values($results//*[name() = $element])  (: $results//genre :)
    let $c := //$results[? = $g]                               (: //$results[genre=$g] :)

 }
```

what should be in place of '?' in variable '$c'

Comment: Good question, +1. Your question isn't very well specified, but in my answer I have tried to guess and to change your code into something that may be useful. :)

Comment: The nice thing about XQuery comments is that you have smiley faces everywhere...

Answer (score 2):

```
function abc ($results as element()*, $element as xs:string) 
 { 
    for $g in distinct-values($results//*[name() = $element])  (: $results//genre :) 
    let $c := //$results[? = $g]                               (: //$results[genre=$g] :) 

 }
```

> what should be in place of '?' in
>   variable '$c'

**It is a syntax error to write**:

```
//$results
```

**This question is rather vague**, but it seems to me that you want to group the elements, contained in `$results` according to their `genre` (or whatever element name defined by `$element` -- BTW this name sucks (an element isn't a string) -- better use `$elementName`).

**The other concerning fact is** that you check the complete subtrees topped by each of the elements in `$results` -- this means that they may have multiple `genre` (or whatever) descendents.

**To finalize my guessing spree**, it seems to me that you want this:

```
function grouping-Keys ($elems as element()*, $subElementName as xs:string) as element()* 
 { 
    for $g in distinct-values($elems//*[name() = $subElementName ]) 
     return 
       $elems[//*[name() = $subElementName ] = $g][1]     
 }
```

**If it is known that `$subElementName` is a name of a child** that any of the elements in `$elems` have, then the above should be better written as:

```
function grouping-Keys ($elems as element()*, $childElementName as xs:string) as element()* 
 { 
    for $g in distinct-values($elems/*[name() = $childElementName ]) 
     return 
       $elems[/*[name() = $subElementName ] = $g][1]     
 }
```

Both of the above functions return one element per a (distinct value of) genre (or whatever). If it is known (guaranteed) that every element in `$elems` has exactly one child (descendent) named genre (or whatever), then the results of these functions are not redundant.